# How to add rows with specific values to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have the following df consisting of x values and their probabilities starting with x=19 and ending with x=64.

```
      x    probability
0   19.0    1.000000
1   20.0    1.000000
2   21.0    1.000000
3   22.0    1.000000
...
40  60.0    0.000000
41  62.0    0.500000
42  63.0    1.000000
43  64.0    0.000000
```

What I would like to do is add rows ranging from x=65 to x=100 and have all of their probabilities be equal to 0, like so:

```
      x     probability
0   19.0     1.000000
1   20.0     1.000000
2   21.0     1.000000
3   22.0     1.000000
4   23.0     1.000000
...
43  64.0     0.000000
44  65.0     0.000000
43  66.0     0.000000
44  67.0     0.000000
...
73  97.0     0.000000
78  98.0     0.000000
79  99.0     0.000000
80  100.0    0.000000
```

Again, I would simply like to add consecutive x values from 65 to 100 with a probability of 0. I'm not quite sure how to add rows like this, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Note: This question is similar to [add specific number of rows to dataframe (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61501074/add-specific-number-of-rows-to-dataframe-python), but I want my values in the column x to increase by 1 each time instead of stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `reindex`

```
df_new=df.set_index('x').reindex(np.arange(df.x.min(),100+1),method='ffill').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create a second dataframe and append with `df.append()`

your dataframe can be created with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(19, 65)})
df['probability'] = 1
```

create a second dataframe and append it to the first one like

```
max_x = df['x'].max()
df_append = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(max_x, 101)})
df_append['probability'] = 0

df_res = df.append(df_append)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to generate a list and append the dataframe with `df.append(...)`

```
x = []
probabilities = []
for i in range(65,101):
  x.append(i)
  probabilities.append(0)
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'probabilites':probabilities})

df.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)
```